# Quelle est l'étymologie de la forme pronominale du verbe agir?

Tags: sens, expressions, étymologie, littérature

Je cherche à comprendre l’utilisation du verbe agir sous sa forme pronominale impersonnelle : « Il s’agit de », en son sens premier.

Quelle est l'action et en quoi le sujet agit-il sur lui-même?

S’il s’agit d’une expression, d’où provient-elle ? Quelle en est ses premières utilisations dans la langue française ?

« En étymologie, il s’agit de comprendre le sens premier des mots. »

L’académie en son dictionnaire note le sens :

▪  [Être agi (rare)](https://www.dictionnaire-academie.fr/article/A9A0862), agir sous l’impulsion ou la détermination d’une puissance extérieure à sa volonté. L’homme est agi par le destin, par la nécessité.

Ce sens éclaire, tout au moins en mon esprit, les utilisations suivantes :

« Quand on ne le saurait pas toujours, ce mot, dérivé du bas latin carra, a, bien avant qu’il ne fût question de gueuleton, désigné le visage : [il s’est d’abord agi,](https://www.projet-voltaire.fr/regles-orthographe/faire-bonne-chair-ou-faire-bonne-chere/) ni plus ni moins, de recevoir dignement celui qui, sans forcément s’être annoncé, frappait à la porte »!

« Quelle ne fut pas ma surprise, ce mardi, alors que je musardais sur la Toile, de tomber sur cet os grammatical : il aurait s’agit, en lieu et place de : [il se serait agi](http://parler-francais.eklablog.com/y-a-comme-un-os-a131482598). »

« Il » se rapportait à ce qui est énoncé précédemment, agissant de par lui-même, sa propre nature ou fonction.

Ainsi, l’objet de l’étymologie, sa fonction intrinsèque et son action serait de susciter comprendre le sens premier des mots.

L’impulsion de l’étymologie, sa puissance, déterminait et s’imposerait à la volonté des femmes et des hommes.

« Il s’agit de », serait une figure littéraire qui transmute l’objet en sujet, acteur ?

Comment: Une hypothèse: Agir = faire, produire (cf https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/agir). Il s'agit X = on fait X, il se produit X. Il s'agit de = ce qui est en train de se produire porte sur/concerne...

Comment: Merci, Guillaume. Je comprends le sens de l’expression. L’utilisation de la forme pronominale m’échappe.

Comment: Je pense à une forme pronominale à sens passif, comme dans "il se dit que...", "il se vend X exemplaires de ce livre", etc. Mais vieillie dans le cas de "il s'agit X". La définition du cnrtl propose un exemple similaire avec "s'agir à" dans la partie histoire et étymologie.

Answer (score 0):

> Quelle est l'action et en quoi le sujet agit-il sur lui-même?

Je crois que la clé réside dans l'exemple de l'Ac. et le commentaire de guillaume31.

> L’homme est agi par la nécessité.

Le verbe est *agir*, la voix *passive*, le sujet *l'homme* et l'agent, *la nécessité*. Au moins syntaxiquement, "l'homme est agi **de** la nécessité" est également acceptable.
Pouvons-nous adapter ce modèle au cas d'un sujet impersonnel et d'un agent qui est une subordonnée?

"Il est agi de décamper au plus vite."

Bof...  Et si l'agent reste un groupe nominal?

"Il est agi d'inhalations."

Re-bof...

Donc, pour des raisons purement syntaxiques, le **sens** passif est marqué préférentiellement par une **forme** pronominale: *il s'agit de décamper au plus vite.* Passe-partout, elle devient la seule possible.

> « Il s’agit de », serait une figure littéraire qui transmute l’objet
> en sujet, acteur ?

Pas spécifiquement; c'est la forme pronominale à sens passif qui est cette figure. Par exemple, si je veux le sens *Il est pu* (verbe pouvoir, forme impersonnelle, voix passive) *que nous soyons à l'heure* (subordonnée à fonction d'agent), la syntaxe exige "il se peut que nous soyons à l'heure".